# Codecademy javascript Number guesser problem

Tags: javascript

So I am working on this project in codecademy that is a number guessing game. I am running into a bit of a kink. When the updateScore function fires, it says undefined. What it should do is update the humanScore variable or the computerScore variable based on the results of compareGuesses. When I put in the value of 'human' it says undefined when it should start adding up from zero. So the first time it is clicked it should be 1 and the second time should be 2 and so on. What am I forgetting or doing wrong?

```js
let humanScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let currentRoundNumber = 1;

// Write your code below:

function generateTarget() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
};

function compareGuesses(humanGuess, computerGuess, generateTarget) {
  let humanValue = Math.abs(humanGuess - generateTarget);
  let computerValue = Math.abs (computerGuess - generateTarget);
  if (humanValue < computerValue) {
    return 'human';
  } else if (humanValue === computerValue) {
    return 'human';
  } else {
    return 'computer';
  }
};

function updateScore(compareGuesses) {
  if (compareGuesses === 'human') {
    humanScore = humanScore + 1;
  } else if (compareGuesses === 'computer') {
    computerScore = computerScore + 1;
  }
};

console.log(updateScore('human'));
```

Comment: In `function compareGuesses` you should use a variable, say: `var generateTargetVar=generateTarget()`, and not try to pass a function into it.
The same with `function updateScore`.

Comment: but when I use the code like ```var humanScore = humanScore ++;``` it only passes a 1, doesn't update per each time the button is clicked.

Comment: I lied. It only passes NaN. Just tested it

Comment: The "whole" point of `++` is to avoid using: `humanScore = humanScore ++`.
Use: `humanScore++` on it's own = it will (use value and then) increase it, vs:
`++humanScore` that will increase it (and then use the increased value).

Comment: Oh so since I want to use the increased value I need to use the ++ in front of humanScore

Comment: No...
`++` will increment the variable "attached" to it: either before use or after == The point was that you don't need to use `somevar = somevar++` = just `somevar++`.
`somevar++` is more common.
`a=somevar++` will set `a` to the value of `somevar` and then increment `someva` by 1,
`a=++somevar` will first increment `somevar`, and then set `a` to the incremented value.

Comment: OH! ok. that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing functions as arguments to other functions and then treating them as a variable.

Here's an updated code:

```js
let humanScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let currentRoundNumber = 1;

// Write your code below:

function generateTarget() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
};

function compareGuesses(humanGuess, computerGuess /*, generateTarget */) {
  let generatedTarget = generateTarget(); // notice the "d"
  let humanValue = Math.abs(humanGuess - generatedTarget);
  let computerValue = Math.abs (computerGuess - generatedTarget);
  if (humanValue <= computerValue) {
    return 'human';
  }
  /* else if (humanValue === computerValue) {
    return 'human';
  } */
  else {
    return 'computer';
  }
};

function updateScore(player) {
  if (player === 'human') {
    humanScore++; // = humanScore + 1;
  }
  else /* if (player === 'computer') */ {
    computerScore++; // = computerScore + 1;
  }
  return "Round "+(currentRoundNumber++)+"\n"+
         "Human: "+humanScore+"\n"+
         "Computer: "+computerScore;
};

console.log(updateScore('human'));
```

You still need to fill-in the rest of the logic of the game.

Comment: Thanks! If I would have use const instead of a function, would what I have work?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer!
I'll be glad to help you with the rest of the logic.
The important part is that you understand how to use functions and their `return`ed values, and what you are passing as an argument (you CAN pass a function as an argument, but mostly, I don't think it will be done).
Up-vote?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think const has anything to do with the problem at hand:
A function either does something or does something and returns a value.
You can set a variable to the returned value.

Comment: Ok. For reference, this is what the finished product should look like: https://content.codecademy.com/PRO/independent-practice-projects/number-guesser/example/index.html

Comment: Also, they wanted another function called advanceRound so where you entered the round number in the updateScore function, I should remove that right?

Comment: I guess so, as you say, "they" want a separate function...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222744/discussion-between-mbmarketing4you-and-iamoren).

Comment: You've left the chat...  Anyways:
What will the `advanceRound` function do?
Will it return a value? If so, of what?
For example, function double(value) - what argument does it take? what does it do with it? what does it return? Be as specific as you can.
What you did, and I'm sure you didn't mean to, was something like this:
`function act(value, func) { func(value); }` which could be used like so:
`act("hello world", alert)` or `act("hello world", console.log)`...